# More Than one Column under same column Heading like Colspan

Tags: sql-server

is it possible to get this output from select Query

[image]

I tried the below query

> select monthly + savings as monthly savings from table

but the resultant data is under one column

is there any solution to get more than one column under same heading

Comment: This is something which can and should be handed in your presentation layer.  Your query above is probably as close as you will get with pure SQL Server.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I tried to do in presentation layer as am working with dynamic column creation achieving this using telerik radgrid is not possible

Comment: Then the best you can do might be to output your query in monospaced font and try to format columns yourself.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to retrieve the information from SQL Server with merged headers, at least not with the most widely used clients.

SQL Server is a relational database and it's fundation is based on sets of data arranged in tables with columns, rows and relationships between them. Suppresing a header would mean breaking the column-value link. If you want to manipulate them, you will have to do so after retrieving the data from the database, maybe on your display layer or in a helper process between the database and your presentation, as Tim suggested.